# While building my NativeScript app for iOS I get CFBundleIdentifier not set

Tags: nativescript

> Project successfully built. The build result is located at:
>   /Volumes/projects/nativescript/bingoplus/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/bingoplus.app
>   Installing on device BF118DE4-9A73-459B-A223-D5CB324F19AF... Unable to
>   apply changes on device: BF118DE4-9A73-459B-A223-D5CB324F19AF. Error
>   is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install
>   BF118DE4-9A73-459B-A223-D5CB324F19AF
>   /Volumes/projects/nativescript/bingoplus/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/bingoplus.app
>   failed with exit code 22. Error output:  An error was encountered
>   processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22): Failed to
>   install the requested application The bundle identifier of the
>   application could not be determined. Ensure that the application's
>   Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.

Upon seeing that I added the entry to Info.plist but then on rebuild I got:

> [WARNING]: The CFBundleIdentifier key inside the 'Info.plist' will be overriden by the 'id' inside 'package.json'.

And then the same error from above 'The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier."

package.json snippet:

```
{


 "nativescript": {
    "id": "bingo.bingoplus",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug. Upgrade tns-core-modules to 6.0.4

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/5073